# XeLaTeX: Using \foreignlanguage results in an error

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

I'm trying to switch to XeTeX, because I would love to have a better integration of postscript code (and pstricks) in my PDF files. However, I did not succeed completely, one error is left and present in the MWE I have added below:

> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
>
> \l@german
>
> A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,listof=totoc,final,fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{polyglossia} % LuaLaTeX replacement for babel
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{german}{ABC}

\end{document}
```

I have to include some German text in my otherwise completely English book. That's why I have used `\foreignlanguage` which has never been a problem with `pdfLaTeX`.

Comment: It might be preferable to write `\textgerman{ABC}` instead.

Comment: Gives the same error as `\foreignlanguage` does.

Comment: I don't get any errors.

Comment: Complete logfile: http://www.dl6er.de/german.log

Comment: You have only patterns for two languages loaded and probably neither german nor ngerman is one of them.

Comment: That's strange, I have exactly the same versions of all packages, but I get no errors (MiKTeX).

Comment: The same MWE (with minor changes like `polyglossia` -> `babel`, `german` -> `ngerman`, etc.) does not produce any errors when invoked using `pdflatex`. It think this indicates that support for German is properly installed.

Comment: I tried it literally and I have no error --- standard TeXLive full installation on a Linux machine. So it's probably an installation problem of your TeX/LaTeX system. Probably the formats are prepared with different configuration files...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem very specific to the OP

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself and will describe what I did in case somebody else runs into the same problem:

Installing TeXLive "on top" of the old one will not work. The error persists.
One has to delete `/usrlocal/texlive/2013/*` and `/usrlocal/texlive/texmf-local/*` manually. After that, the error no longer occurs after performing a new installation.

However, I cannot explain what might have caused the problem in the first place, as the reinstallation was successful using the same version of `install-tl`.

Comment: You probably had a `language.dat` file in `texmf-local`.